# Jenkins code coverage report trigger fail deploy

Tags: php, symfony, jenkins, capistrano

I want to deploy my symfony2 app with jenkins and capistrano. I've configured my deploy.rb file and into jenkins I execute:

```
#!/bin/sh
cap -v deploy
```

Into the deploy.rb file I have:

```
cd #{release_path} && phpunit --verbose --debug -c app/ --coverage-clover=#{deploy_to}/clover.xml
```

Can I configure jenkins to rollback if the coverage percentage is less than 80% for example?

I saw something about ANT, but I don't want to use it. Can it be made on Capistrano or Jenkins?

If the coverage is less than 80%, it gives me the following:

```
Code coverage enforcement failed for the following metrics:
Methods
Statements
Setting Build to unstable.
Build step 'Publish Clover Coverage Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

But the deploy is finished. I want it to stop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to rollback a deploy.

However, if you can split your task into:

1. code coverage
2. deploy

and if your code coverage returns an appropriate status, there's the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin). One of its supported conditions is to run a script and run or don't run a following build step depending on the script's return status.